# Form Data Not Being Passed On Live Server

Tags: php, jquery

I have a registration form on my website which passes the inputs through JQuery Post and into a PHP file.  This all works fine on my localhost which runs PHP 5.2, but when I upload it to my server (5.4) I'm getting problems with the form not being processed.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
$time = time();
$id= time().'-'.mt_rand(100000000, 999999999);
$type= mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_REQUEST["type"]);
$subtype= mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_REQUEST["subtype"]);
$name= mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_REQUEST["name"]);
$name = ucwords(strtolower($name));
$email= mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_REQUEST["email"]);
$relative= mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_REQUEST["relative"]);
$relative = ucwords(strtolower($relative));
$summary= mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_REQUEST["bio"]);
$postcode= mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_REQUEST["postcode"]);
$sendpassword= mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_REQUEST["password"]);
$password= md5(mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_REQUEST["password"]));
$hash = md5( rand(0,1000) ); // Generate random 32 character hash and assign it to a local variable.
```

Comment: Exact duplicate of [PHP / MySQL Input Not Working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20980715/php-mysql-input-not-working)

Comment: Also duplicated here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20994073/form-not-being-passed-on-server.  Stop posting the same question over and over.

Answer (score 1):

Using `stripslashes` *after* SQL escaping the string is pure nonsense. `mysqli_real_escape_string` specifically *adds* backslashes to the string in order to escape specific characters and make the string safe for insertion as an SQL string literal. `stripslashes` mostly reverses this effect. Ergo, it's pointless.

I'm guessing you have a difference with [Magic Quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) on those two servers; with Magic Quotes it happens to work somehow, without it breaks as it should.

Comment: So you're saying that if I simply get rid of stripslashes from the second line things should work?

Comment: Yes. You'll probably see extra slashes in the database values on your local system due to Magic Quotes, but it will stop breaking on your production system.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $member= stripslashes($_REQUEST["editid"]); 
    //other variables       
    }
//then
$member = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $member);
```